# fetching mail via IMAP in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4, imap

i am trying to fetch my mail from gmail account and store it into my database now i am facing an error during run server using gem 'imap_processor', '~> 1.6'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1057:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "smtp.gmail.com" port 143 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

- Unable to load application: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt
  failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
  period of time, or established connection failed because connected
  host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "smtp.gmail.com" port
  143

  ```
  imap = Net::IMAP.new('smtp.gmail.com')
  imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'debasish.industrify2016@gmail.com', '*******')
  imap.examine('INBOX')
  imap.search(["RECENT"]).each do |message_id|
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  puts "#{envelope.from[0].name}: \t#{envelope.subject}"
  end
  ```

can any one guide me ?

Comment: Please look up the proper service parameters for IMAP.  The server should be imap.gmail.com, SSL is required, and the default port is 993.

Comment: can you tell me ...how can i put ssl and port?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html  Looks like include "ssl" in an options hash.  Use your docs.